# Use buttons generated from xml file to set radiobutton values

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, button, radio-button

Case: My Windows Forms Application is creating buttons and radiobuttons from a XML-file. For every button created(Preset in XML), i want to change the **checked** radiobuttons(Lijst in XML) to the values described in my XML.

My thoughts: There should be a on click method, than it reads the xml value which preset is clicked and change the radiobuttons to the correct value. But I dont have a clue how to do this.

Code of XML:

```
<Lijsten>

   <Lijst>
   <Titel>Discipline</Titel>
   <Waardes>Elektro</Waardes>
   <Waardes>Mechanisch</Waardes>
   <Waardes>Civiel</Waardes>
   <Waardes>Proces</Waardes>
   <Waardes>N.v.t.</Waardes>
   </Lijst>
   <Lijst>
   <Titel>Soort</Titel>
   <Waardes>Tekening</Waardes>
   <Waardes>Tekst doc</Waardes>
   <Waardes>Afbeelding</Waardes>
   <Waardes>N.v.t.</Waardes>
   </Lijst>

   <Preset>
   <ButtonTitel>Preset 1</ButtonTitel>
   <sets>
      <RadioButtonTitel>Discipline</RadioButtonTitel>
      <RadioButtonValue>Elektro</RadioButtonValue>
   </sets>
   <sets>
      <RadioButtonTitel>Soort</RadioButtonTitel>
      <RadioButtonValue>Afbeelding</RadioButtonValue>
   </sets>
   </Preset>
   <Preset>
   <ButtonTitel>Preset 2</ButtonTitel>
   <sets>
      <RadioButtonTitel>Discipline</RadioButtonTitel>
      <RadioButtonValue>Mechanisch</RadioButtonValue>
   </sets>
   <sets>
      <RadioButtonTitel>Soort</RadioButtonTitel>
      <RadioButtonValue>Tekening</RadioButtonValue>
   </sets>
   </Preset>

</Lijsten>
```

Code of creating the radiobuttons:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    radioButtonCounter += 1;
    count += 1;
    if (count < 4)
    {
         int heightRadioButtons = 0;
         WidthPanelsRow1 += 155;
         Panel panel = new Panel();
         panel.Size = new Size(140, 200);
         panel.Location = new Point(WidthPanelsRow1, heightPanelsRow1);
         panel.Name = "panel" + count.ToString();
         panel.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

         Label lbl = new Label();
         lbl.Text = node["Titel"].InnerText;
         lbl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
         lbl.Font = font1;
         panel.Controls.Add(lbl);

         int counterLastRadioButton = 0;
         XmlNodeList waardeNodes = node.SelectNodes("Waardes");
         foreach (XmlNode wNode in waardeNodes)
         {
              counterLastRadioButton += 1;
              heightRadioButtons += 20;
              RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
              rb.Text = wNode.InnerText;
              rb.Location = new Point(5, heightRadioButtons);
              rb.Name = node["Titel"].InnerText;
              if (waardeNodes.Count - 1 < counterLastRadioButton)
              {
                   rb.Checked = true;
              }
              panel.Controls.Add(rb);
         }
         this.Controls.Add(panel);
   }else...
}
```

Code for creating the preset buttons:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
     count += 1;
     if (count < 4)
     {
          WidthPanelsRow1 += 155;
          Panel panel = new Panel();
          panel.Size = new Size(140, 40);
          panel.Location = new Point(WidthPanelsRow1, heightPanelsRow1);
          panel.Name = "panel" + count.ToString();

          XmlNodeList titelPreset = node.SelectNodes("ButtonTitel");
          foreach (XmlNode titelNode in titelPreset)
          {
              Button btn = new Button();
              btn.Text = titelNode.InnerText;
              btn.Location = new Point(0, 0);
              btn.Name = node["ButtonTitel"].InnerText;
              btn.Size = new Size(140,40);
              btn.Click += (sender, args) =>
              {
                   //What to do here?
              };
              panel.Controls.Add(btn);
          }
          this.Controls.Add(panel);
      }else...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I like to create a Dictionary<string,RadioButton>.  You can look up control by title, but it is very slow.  Dictionary would be super fast.

Comment: I'm looking for something fast because the program is created to assign data to an image, and write it into a textfile. The "presets" are there so the user does not have to change 9 radiobuttons values if the "preset" is common. But I dont have a clue to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dictionaries.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RadioButton>> radioPanels = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RadioButton>>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            int radioButtonCounter = 0;
            int count = 0;
            int WidthPanelsRow1 = 100;
            int heightPanelsRow1 = 50;
            Font font1 = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(FILENAME);
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Lijst");

            Dictionary<string, RadioButton> dictRadioButtons;
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                radioButtonCounter += 1;
                count += 1;
                if (count < 4)
                {
                    int heightRadioButtons = 0;
                    WidthPanelsRow1 += 155;
                    Panel panel = new Panel();
                    panel.Size = new Size(140, 200);
                    panel.Location = new Point(WidthPanelsRow1, heightPanelsRow1);
                    panel.Name = "panel" + count.ToString();
                    panel.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = node["Titel"].InnerText;
                    lbl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                    lbl.Font = font1;
                    panel.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    dictRadioButtons = new Dictionary<string, RadioButton>();
                    radioPanels.Add(lbl.Text, dictRadioButtons);

                    int counterLastRadioButton = 0;
                    XmlNodeList waardeNodes = node.SelectNodes("Waardes");
                    foreach (XmlNode wNode in waardeNodes)
                    {
                        counterLastRadioButton += 1;
                        heightRadioButtons += 20;
                        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                        rb.Text = wNode.InnerText;
                        rb.Location = new Point(5, heightRadioButtons);
                        rb.Name = node["Titel"].InnerText;
                        if (waardeNodes.Count - 1 < counterLastRadioButton)
                        {
                            rb.Checked = true;
                        }
                        panel.Controls.Add(rb);
                        dictRadioButtons.Add(rb.Text, rb);

                    }
                    this.Controls.Add(panel);

                    int countA = 0;
                    foreach (XmlNode nodeA in nodes)
                    {
                        countA += 1;
                        if (countA < 4)
                        {
                            WidthPanelsRow1 += 155;
                            Panel panelA = new Panel();
                            panelA.Size = new Size(140, 40);
                            panelA.Location = new Point(WidthPanelsRow1, heightPanelsRow1);
                            panelA.Name = "panel" + count.ToString();

                            XmlNodeList titelPreset = node.SelectNodes("ButtonTitel");
                            foreach (XmlNode titelNode in titelPreset)
                            {
                                Button btn = new Button();
                                btn.Text = titelNode.InnerText;
                                btn.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                                btn.Name = nodeA["ButtonTitel"].InnerText;
                                btn.Size = new Size(140, 40);

                            }
                            this.Controls.Add(panelA);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            XmlNodeList presets = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Preset");
            XmlNodeList radioButtonValues = presets[0].SelectNodes("sets");

            foreach (XmlNode rbNode in radioButtonValues)
            {
                Dictionary<string, RadioButton> rbPanel = radioPanels[rbNode.SelectNodes("RadioButtonTitel")[0].InnerText];
                RadioButton rb = rbPanel[rbNode.SelectNodes("RadioButtonValue")[0].InnerText];
                rb.Checked = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, give me a moment to test it.

Comment: When i test this code in a empty project i get the following error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" at line: "Dictionary<string, RadioButton> rbPanel = radioPanels[rbNode.SelectNodes("RadioButtonTitel")[0].InnerText];".

Comment: Thanks btw for the great effort, u want me to provide an image of the error details?

Comment: The name of radio button wasn't added to the dictionary, or the preset names aren't matching the actual name of the control.First check rbNopde and rbPanel to see which panel has the issue.  Then compare the xml name.

Comment: Oke, thats fixed, but somehow there are no buttons for the presets. I've added " panelA.Controls.Add(btn);", but still no buttons. This list seems to be empty: " XmlNodeList titelPreset = node.SelectNodes("ButtonTitel");".
Sorry if im a bit of a noob in this, im still a student.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct answer? Because if i want to change the radiobutton values with a preset, i would have to click on the preset button and the radiobutton values will change.. I dont see a button on click method, are we on the same page?

Comment: Example: i click on the button "preset 1", the values of radiobox "discipline" will change from its default to "Elektro", and the values of radiobix "Soort" will change from its default to "Afbeelding" (described in xml).

Comment: You don't change the radio button values.  They normally remain the same.  You change the radioButton that is checked to switch from one radio button to another.  So the presets are just changing the button that is checked.  If you place the radio button into a Group then only one button will be checked for each group.  If you don't but them into a group then when you check one button you must unchecked all the others in the group.

Comment: Indeed, we change the value in a group, so another radiobutton wil be checked. But dont we need a button on click function here?Because the radiobuttons will switch when we click the preset button. Also my  " XmlNodeList titelPreset = node.SelectNodes("ButtonTitel");" is empty so its not creating any buttons.

Comment: So why are you trying to preset a button that doesn't exist?  The click event is only needed if you want to execute code when the button is pressed.  Often on a form you will select lots of options and then press a run button to execute code after all the option are selected.  So you only need a click event for run and not every control.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you trying to say, when i click on the button, code will be executed so the values of radiobutton group will switch to another value right? Thats how i should approach it, you sure we on the same line? And can you tell me why "XmlNodeList titelPreset = node.SelectNodes("ButtonTitel");" is empty? XML file clearly contains "ButtonTitel".

Comment: If you want i can provide you a onedrive link so you can download the complete project to get a better understanding?